# Viewpager no longer swipeable after onClick is set on inflated View

Tags: android, android-layout, onclick, android-viewpager

I have a viewpager, which contain an image. If I create the image view using an xml layout as below

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, final int position) {
    final int realPosition = getItemPosition(position);
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_adsong, container, false);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.adsong_img);
    /... set to the image.../

    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onClickPage(realPosition);
        }
    });
    container.addView(view);
    return view;
}
```

After adding the onClickListener, I can no longer swipe my view pager from page to page. Without the onClickListener, I could do so.

However, if I create my ImageView from the code (instead of using xml layout) as below

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, final int position) {
    final int realPosition = getItemPosition(position);
    ImageView view = new ImageView(mContext);
    /... set to the image.../

    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onClickPage(realPosition);
        }
    });
    container.addView(view);
    return view;
}
```

I could now swipe the view pager, and I could do the click as I like. Why my first example above is intercepting the swipe, while the second is not? How could I fix my first example above to allow both swipe and onClick still work (I prefers using the layout, as I have several more e.g. some TextViews than just ImageView to show in my view pager). Thanks!

Comment: Try changing your inflate call: `View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_adsong, null)` I doubt you intend to inherit the layout parameters of your viewpager onto your view item.

Comment: Tried that, not working :(

Comment: Can you post the rest of your pager adapter code?

Comment: Sorry, it involve some inherited classes, hence would complicate things to show all. The main thing is, with slight different of creating the page with ImageView directly, the onClick is not intercepting the swipe. But when we use layout inflated, it is not working. Perhaps some advice how could I debug further would help as well.

Comment: I think you should make sure you are actually adding multiple views and that `getCount()` matches correctly for starters.

Comment: The getCount() all works fine. I have two pages, and it could swipe without issue if the onClick listener is not there.

Comment: Tried both clickable true and false. Same behavior. It seems to be the touch has been hijacked by the "View" even it is a swipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further thorough debug and investigation, found the issue as per https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/wIqNP4fzJQc. The cause of the issue is because the existence of TextView in my .xml layout. The TextView is scrollable by default.

Given the TextView is scrollable, the ViewPager then would allow the text to scroll by not intercepting the scrolling touch, and passing to the child. Hence the scrolling touch of the ViewPager is not working.

To fix the problem I override the `canScrollHorizontal` function of the TextView to return false. This solve the problem

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView {
    //...
    @Override
    public boolean canScrollHorizontally(int direction) {
        return false;
    }
    //....
```

Note: using `setHorizontallyScrolling(false`) or setting the `android:scrollHorizontally="false"` attribute in the XML of the TextView doesn't solve the problem somehow.

Hope this helps some who face the ViewPager no longer scrollable issue.